# No se renderiza componentes de react router en el servidor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

como están? Ojala me puedan ayudar, es algo que no logro solucionar y realmente necesito que funcione.

Tengo una aplicación que utiliza react router pero solo con dos rutas, de la siguiente manera

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import DuneApp from "../components/DuneApp";

const AppRouter = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="container">
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={DuneApp} />
                    <Route exact path="/uploaded/:videoId" component={DuneApp} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default AppRouter;
```

pero al momento de hacer el build, en el html solo aparece el div con la clase container y no se renderiza el componente que están dentro del switch.

Por favor, si me pueden ayudar estaría super agradecido

Comment: Ok entonces si funciona en la versión `dev`, saludos

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema AYUDA
El Componente me funciona perfecto pero no me funciona cuando lo coloco en el Switch, no me da error ni en terminal ni en consola.GRACIAS